# Manatee.json - how to serialize using camelcase naming

Tags: c#, json, serialization, manatee.json

Some frameworks like JSON.NET, you can serialize an object to json CamelCase naming like this:

```
 User user1 = new User
{
    UserName = "jamesn",
    Enabled = true
};

DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user1, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = contractResolver,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
});
```

Is there any similar way how to do this using Manatee.JSON? I haven't found any documentation about this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Manatee.JSON provides a delegate so that you can transform property names at serialization time.

I used the following to turn my PascalCase properties into camelCase:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer
{
  Options = {SerializationNameTransform = s => s.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + s.Substring(1)}
};
```

Figured out I could do this by reviewing [Manatee.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerOptions](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Json/blob/master/Manatee.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerOptions.cs) on GitHub.